# Proving a jump discontinuity with topologic definition

Tags: general-topology, continuity

If you have a map $f : (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T}) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T})$ given as $f(x):=3$ for $x \neq 1$ and $f(x):=4$ for $x=1$, being $\mathcal{T}$ the usual topology in $\mathbb{R}$.

How do you prove that $f$ is not continious? I mean, using the definition of continuity used in Topology. What open subset $U$ of $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T})$ do you need to prove $f^{-1}(U)$ is not open in $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T})$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open set $U=\{x\neq 3\}$ should work. Notice that you could equally exhibit a *closed* set whose preimage is not closed, e.g. the obvious set $\{3\}$.

Comment: Can you explain it in more detail, please? For example, $U = (0,1)$ you get $f^{-1}(U) = \emptyset$?

Comment: I'm considering the set of all real numbers without 3. It is open since $\{3\}$ is closed, and its preimage is $\{1\}$, which is not open. In general you may take $U$ to be an open set which contains 4 and not 3.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, how does the usual metric definition correspond to the topological one?

Here this means that $f$ is continuous at $x$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that whenever $|x-y|<\delta$, we have that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$.

In other words, this means that the preimage of the interval $(f(x)-\varepsilon,f(x)+\varepsilon)$ contains the interval $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$.

---

We know that this is not true for $f$ as you defined it, but only for the case $x=1$. So let us pick some $\varepsilon>0$, say $\varepsilon=1/2$, and let us see if we can find an interval around $1$ that works. But the answer to that, of course, is no. The interval $(1/2,3/2)$ has the preimage $\{1\}$, and does not contain any interval around $1$ for any $\delta>0$.

But now this is exactly the open set we wanted!